# How do I edit a symlink using Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, symlink

On GitHub I can view symlinks as text - they are just a path to the target. 
However, if I edit a symlink in Atom it opens the file that the symlink points to. This is reasonable behaviour but not what I am trying to do.

Can I edit them in a similar way using Atom on my local machine?

If now, is there another text editor that can?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a symbolic link's target by editing the symlink file.

There are cases where the target of a symlink is stored in the symlink file, but that is not usually the case. For most target paths, the target is stored in the inode data directly.

Then there are symlink-like things various filesystems have implemented, such as macOS aliases, or Windows NTFS which has symlinks but they are not exactly the same as Unix/POSIX symlinks.

To manage symlinks you should be using the tools your OS provides, such as the `ln` command.

That said, I'm not aware of any packages for Atom which offer an in-editor method of managing symlinks. The tree-view package does not seem to offer it.